# What was Charles' problem with the plumbing?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, beetlejuice

When the Deetzes are first moving into the Maitland's home, Charles says "We're going to have to rip out all that plumbing, but other than that it's perfect"- why would he see the need to "rip out the plumbing" in an otherwise "perfect" house?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

Because it's old and noisy.

The line does not appear in the [version of the script I found](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/beetlejuice_skaaren_final.html) but there is a more informative wording that would appear to explain it.

> ```
>                            CHARLES
>              The noise in that kitchen.  Noisy
>              refrigerator, noisy faucets...
>              We'll have to replace it all.  I
>              want no humming in the house.
> ```